# How can I read a txt file for a specific time limit?

Tags: python

I want to read a text file containing many URLs (like around 10k) and I want to read that text file for 30 seconds and only convert those URLs to the list which are being read within that 30 seconds.

Is this possible in python by using any library?
Just give me the direction I will figure out the rest myself.

Comment: What code are you using to read the file?  What do you want to time out after 30s?  On my system I can read 10k lines of a text file in a lot less than 30s (depending on what I do with the lines).

Comment: I want to read text files that have lots of URLs (Imagine it as a web crawler), I will store only those URLs in my crawler which are being read in only the first 30 seconds. Rest URLs will be ignored.
So my point is not reading 10k URLs, my point is reading only those URLs which can be read for the first 30 secs. imagine if someone has a web crawler and he has a text file with infinite URLs..

Comment: So are you *crawling* those urls?  We really need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time module of python, I suggest you, add a timer in the function if the timer goes to 30sec, then just break it.

---

you can refer to this.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/

Comment: Should be pointed out that simply adding a timer and checking it will slow down the file reading process unless its in a different thread

Comment: yes! it'll slow down the code. But it's what he wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, guys I solved the problem.
I used `start = time.time()` for capturing the start time and then I used `while(time.time() - start <= 30)` for running this loop only for 30 seconds. Inside that I used the `.readline()` method to read the line one by one and did `.append()` to append that line into my URLs list.